# Error when updating node following command npm i npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I get the following error after I return a command

`npm i npm`

My node version is *6.2.0*

```
C:\Users\Shihas>npm i npm
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID
npm ERR! errno ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: Hostname/IP d
oes not match certificate's altnames: Host: registry.npmjs.org. is not in the ce
rt's altnames: DNS:a.sni.fastly.net, DNS:a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shihas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-01T10_10_11
_873Z-debug.log
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing npm i -g npm or just npm i npm?

Comment: @vito just npm i npm

Comment: Try npm i -g npm then.

Comment: @vito it seems to work . i got this error now when i try to install angular cli

Comment: @vito C:\Users\Shihas>npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error: @angular/cli@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shihas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-01T10_36_50
_454Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem like you are behind a proxy or something wrong with the network so it can't verify https certificate.

You can try to add this `npm config set strict-ssl false` to disable ssl check and then try it install again

Comment: Seems to be a global configuration error, see https://status.npmjs.org/

Comment: Bypassing strict-ssl does not help unfortunately - npm responds with 500 Internal Server Error.